# Resolving a symlink without readlink utility

Tags: perl, symlink, aix

I am trying to use a perl one liner to print a string using regex match in unix command line pipeline.

`ls -l /APPL`

gives output

`lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     system            4 Nov 27 12:07 /APPL -\> /PRD`

My goal is to print `'PRD'`

the command I am using

`ls -l /APPL | perl -ne 'print "$1\\n" if / \/APPL\s\S+\s\s\/(\S+)\s/'`

I was tracking it with regex debugger https://regex101.com/ and it looks like it looses it at **\/**(\S+)\s

I am using AIX on a system without the `readlink` command-line utility. I know I could use awk, but this is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: `perl -E 'say readlink("/APPL")'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prints the value of a symlink:

```bash
readlink /APPL
```

```bash
perl -le'print readlink( $ARGV[0] )' /APPL
```

Converts to an absolute path with all symlinks (if any) resolved:

```bash
readlink -e /APPL
```

```bash
perl -MCwd=abs_path -le'print abs_path( $ARGV[0] )' /APPL
```

```bash
perl -le'use Cwd qw( abs_path ); print abs_path( $ARGV[0] )' /APPL
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the single command line (implies `GNU/Linux` like OS, `*BSD`):

```
echo $(basename $(readlink /APPL))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was not able to run readlink command directly on AIX

Comment: It would have been interesting to produce this information from the beginning.

Comment: Very true. I just edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match because you match two consecutive spaces between the greater than sign and the backslash at the start of "PRD". Replace that with a single space at it seems to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$_ = 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root system 4 Nov 27 12:07 /APPL -> /PRD';

if (m[/APPL\s\S+\s/(\S+)]) {
  say $1;
} else {
  warn "No match\n";
}
```

Note that I've also replaced `/.../` with `m[...]` so that I can use `/` in my regex without escaping it.

**However** as others have noted - this is the wrong approach. If you're trying to work out where a symbolic link points to, then you should use the [`readlink()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readlink) function.

Comment: Thanks - I must have missed that another space and your solution worked with no issues.

I will explore readlink() fuction ofcourse. Thanks a lot

Comment: Parsing `ls` should be avoided. You need 10 lines of `perl` where a simple shell command can handle it better

Comment: Unfortunately there is no readlink available on AIX so it has to be done another way

Comment: @Ikegami gave you the best answer, don't use this please

Comment: @LomakoPakula: I'm talking about Perl's function `readlink()`, not the shell command. There's nothing in [perlport](https://metacpan.org/dist/perl/view/pod/perlport.pod#readlink) about it not working on AIX.

Comment: @GillesQuenot: Yes, I said it was the wrong approach. But sometimes people ignore good advice (sometimes they even have good reasons for ignoring it) so I often take the time to fix their bad code too :-)

Comment: Take care of [butterfly effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) ;)